# Hatched Shadow Is It Possible

Tags: shaders, shadows, scene

https://youtu.be/TWADzTHCzoM
hey how can I create a scene like in this youtube video. This one was done in UE4 but I want to know how recreate it in blender.
As far as I can find only hatched shader on an object and not on the shadow.

Comment: https://entagma.com/create-a-procedural-hatching-shader-in-blender-cycles/

Answer (score 1):

Very lazy attempt at this:

[image]

To me it looks like the reference is using UV direction to guide the lines.

Comment: that looks cool, i need to try that. Thanks. Do you apply the material on all of the objects?

Comment: Yep, everything here has the same shader including the floor.